# How can i get Entity Framework to recognise columns from dynamic stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4 and we have a bunch of stored procedures in our model. Currently we can do everything we need. However we have a new procedure that takes a string, and ultimately performs something such as

```
Create Procedure usp_RunSearch
  @searchTerm VARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)
  SET @sql = '
  SELECT ID,
         NAME
  FROM   Users'

  IF(ISNULL(@searchTerm, '') != '')
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE ' + @searchTerm
  END

  Exec (@sql)
END
```

to return the result-set.

EF does not seem to be able to interrogate this procedure to get the resultant column list.

Is there anything i can do to help EF get over this hurdle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i have created a ComplexType by hand in the EDMX and setup the function import for the stored procedure to use this manually defined complex type. I think that when EF inspects the sproc it can't figure the return set of columns, even though the select list is relatively static in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use it, you can do so.
check this link out.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/04/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-10-raw-sql-queries.aspx

Btw, try adding a default value for the stored procedure parameter, that might also work.

```
Create Procedure usp_RunSearch
  @searchTerm VARCHAR(2000) = ''
AS
```

Comment: I tried this, and also setting the default to be null. I think the best solution is to create my complex type and map it in the function import. this just means we will have to keep track of the complex type definition against the sproc return columns

Comment: Btw, I don't know why do you need that sp, but you might be looking for Dynamic Linq. Dynamiq Linq would make an sp like that almost unnecessary. Just in case you are unaware of what Dynamic Linq is here is a link, it might be outdated tough. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx